# Ignore logs generated by child threads

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

Application I'm currently developing runs some independent library code which outputs loads of logs to the stdout via PrintWriter. Additionally, tasks handled by the library are run in the seperate threads. I'd like to find out if it's possible to ignore (prevent logs from appearing on the console) those logs. However, I can't directly modify the library code, so simple solution is out of question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Which lilbrary is it? Or to be precise: is it using some logging framework? If it just prints stuff to console using `System.out` that it is basically a *Poorly Written Library (tm)*. In that case everything you can do is to redirect `System.out` to [slft4j](/questions/tagged/slft4j) using [System Out and Err redirected to SLF4J](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/index.html). Basically it override default console using [`System.setErr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and [`System.setOut()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29).

If your library uses *any* logging framework (probably `java.util.logging`) try to figure out which loggers/categories does it use and filter them out in your logging framework.

Note that I am not mentioning anything about threads. Filtering logs/console output based on current thread is a bit tricky, use loggers hierarchy instead in your logging framework of choice.

Comment: Library is known as [ECJ](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/) and I use it for research purposes. Unfortunately, it doesn't rely on any logging facility, and directly prints to the console using System.out.

Comment: @voo: I had a look at the source code of ECJ. You are right, it uses `System.out`/`err` directly. Try [System Out and Err redirected to SLF4J](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/index.html) with SLF4J, maybe it'll help. Also see my update.

Comment: System Out and Err redirected to SLF4J doesn't work since ECJ uses wrapped `System.out.write` calls. See this [FAQ](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/faq.html#writingConsole)